# How can i join 2 product collections (Magento)

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I have configurable products that are placed in categories.

example:

configurable product: shirt in category with id 6.

this product has multiple simple products: green shirt with attribute 'size' = XL, L and M.

together this is one product in the shop.

no i want a collection so i can select all simple products with 'size' = XL and where the configurable product of the simple product is in category with id 6.

i think i need to join 2 collections (simple + configurable).
But i can't find info about it on the web. 
somebody a solution?

Comment: It is difficult to understand "...i want a collection with all simple products without a value for 'size' and the configurable products must be in a specific category", probably because English is not your native language. Can you edit your question and change how this is phrased? It will be easier to answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to join 2 collections for this, you can simpy get the childproducts based on the parent.

//loop trough configurable products

$simpleProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $product);

edit or simplified : $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();  this would be the best solution

Comment: if i do that, my collection is to big, and it takes to long to run. if i can filter and join 2 collections, it's faster